# Selenium Python - Disable CSS on Chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm spending a lot of time disabling CSS on chrome web-driver, I do this, but it didn't work.
(I don't want the browser in Headless mode)

Can anyone have an idea to disable CSS only?

Thanks.

```
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.css": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it should disable all the CSS in a webpage

from selenium import webdriver

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'cookies': 2, 'images': 2, 'javascript': 2, 
                            'plugins': 2, 'popups': 2, 'geolocation': 2, 
                            'notifications': 2, 'auto_select_certificate': 2, 'fullscreen': 2, 
                            'mouselock': 2, 'mixed_script': 2, 'media_stream': 2, 
                            'media_stream_mic': 2, 'media_stream_camera': 2, 'protocol_handlers': 2, 
                            'ppapi_broker': 2, 'automatic_downloads': 2, 'midi_sysex': 2, 
                            'push_messaging': 2, 'ssl_cert_decisions': 2, 'metro_switch_to_desktop': 2, 
                            'protected_media_identifier': 2, 'app_banner': 2, 'site_engagement': 2, 
                            'durable_storage': 2}}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://play.google.com/store')
```